# Truncate lines of csv document and write it to a separate column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to shorten each line of a csv document according to a specific number of characters so that, for example, each line is shortened to 12 characters long: [image]

After that, the goal is to write the shortened text in a separate column.
I get a very messy output using the code I wrote. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding='utf8', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    shortened = str(row[2])[:12]
    print(shortened)
df["truncated"] = shortened
df.to_csv("filename2.csv", index=False, encoding="utf8")
```

The output I'm getting:
[image]

"“Old DVDs”I battled over Herbie Hancock " is the beginning of a last row in the file.

Comment: Please include the output you are getting along with a print stamens once you are in the for loop to see the contents of the row. Just a few samples should be fine

Comment: `df['text'].str[:12]` should work, you don't need to loop

Comment: @KalebaKBKeitshokile done!

Comment: The reason why your ```df['truncated']``` is the same for each row is  because you are setting that entire column equal to the value of shortened for the last iteration of the of loop.

Comment: @Manakin yes, it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

So to solve the sameple data you provided you can use this:

```
examples = ['I like cats and dogs',
            'I like ice-cream',
            'She likes to sleep']

examples_shortened = [example[:12] for example in examples]
```

You can then employ the same method on you df like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding='utf8', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
shortened = [example[:12] for example in df['text'].to_list()]
df["truncated"] = shortened
df.to_csv("filename2.csv", index=False, encoding="utf8")
```